# How can i add common headers in separate file in Xcode and access from other classes?

Tags: header

I want to create a separate file in which i will be keeping headers for other classes to use so that i don't have to declare common ones in each files.

Answer (score 1):

Include all your headers in the prefix.pch file

Answer (score -1):

I figured it can be set under target-build settings-> apple llvm compiler - language -> prefix header. add path to prefix.pch file and add all the headers in that file. should work.

Answer (score -1):

where targer-build file is located in magento

I figured it can be set under target-build settings-> apple llvm compiler - language -> prefix header. add path to prefix.pch file and add all the headers in that file. should work.